# Making longest string with substrings from an array

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

I wanna understand how Can I do this:
I am given an array of strings in python such as:

```
Array1 = [‘co’, ‘dil’, ‘ity’]
enter code here
```

I am trying to make a function which should calculate the length of the longest string S such that:
S is a concatenation of some of the strings from A and every letter in S is different.
Example:
Given `A = ['co’, ’dil', ’ity’]`. The function should return 5. The resulting string S could be "codil", "dilco", "coity" or "Ityco".

Comment: Here's a hint. Start by wring a function: `def canAppendString(s1, s2):`. The function returns False if there's any chars in `s1` that are also in `s2`.  Returns True otherwise .  Now build a solution using that function.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that each word in the `Array1` is a verticle in a graph. One node is connected to another node if the two corresponding words have no common letters. Each node has a weight that equals the length of the word. Now the problem transforms into the following: find the maximum (by weight) clique (subsets of vertices, all adjacent to each other, also called complete subgraphs) in a graph. This is a well-known NP-complete problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem), which has no efficient solution:

> To find a maximum clique, one can systematically inspect all subsets, but this sort of brute-force search is too time-consuming to be practical for networks comprising more than a few dozen vertices. Although no polynomial time algorithm is known for this problem, more efficient algorithms than the brute-force search are known. For instance, the Bron–Kerbosch algorithm can be used to list all maximal cliques in worst-case optimal time, and it is also possible to list them in polynomial time per clique.

Answer (score 0):

I would first map each word to a set of characters, so that you can more quickly find out whether two words share a character. We could also find out which characters are used in the input (the alphabet) and then convert each word to a bitmap where each bit represents one character from that alphabet. This is just an implementation of a set, but for small alphabets (like a..z) this will work faster.

Then perform a trivial recursive search. This is not the most efficient. If the input consists of meaningful words, then the alphabet is limited, and so the longest possible word is limited in length too, and the words that partake in it are also limited. This may make it acceptable to have such a brute force algorithm.

In the below code it is assumed that the input words consist only of lowercase
letters from the Latin alphabet:

```
def bitmap(word):
    bits = 0
    for letter in word:
        bits |= 1 << (ord(letter) - ord('a'))
    return bits

def solve(words):
    words = [(bitmap(word), word) for word in set(words)]
    
    def recur(allbits, i):
        longest = ""
        for j in range(i, len(words)):
            bits, word = words[j]
            if (bits & allbits) == 0:
                result = word + recur(allbits | bits, j + 1)
                if len(result) > len(longest):
                    longest = result
        return longest

    return recur(0, 0)
```

Here is an example run:

```
words = "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua ut enim ad minim veniam quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum".split(" ")

print(solve(words))  # ullamcoreprehenderit
```